# harcascadePath = cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, attributeerror, face-recognition

I am trying to trying to make an face and eyes detection using haarcascade. While running it threw harcascadePath = cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' error.
The error didn't came for face but it came for eyes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyes_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')


cap=cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\face-demographics-walking-and-pause.mp4")

while True:
    ret,img=cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
        roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        eyes=eyes_cascade.detectMultiscale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey,eh),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(30) and 0xff
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error was

```
AttributeError: 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute 'detectMultiscale'
PS C:\Users\intel\Documents\code\python>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `detectMultiScale` method only accepts the xmls from `opencv\data\haarcascades` path. Especially for `opencv` version 3.4.8 and above

Answer (score 1):

The error of your code should be in the line 13. "detectMultiscale" you must write the first letter 'scale' in upper case.

**detectMultiScale**

I hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.haarcascades` Base Dir for **haarcascades_default**

```
print(cv2.haarcascades) # D:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\data\
cv2.CascadeClassifier(f'{cv2.haarcascades}haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wrote detectMultiscale incorrectly because it is 3 words and are separated by camel casing and is **detectMultiScale**.

Also I think that the 5th and 6th line where it says

> face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
> eyes_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

should be

> face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades
> +'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +'haarcascade_eye.xml')

Thanks